# Are 1,000 threads normal for services.exe?

Tags: windows-7, windows, services, cpu-usage, threads

I noticed that my system is slowing down and services.exe often uses quite some CPU (around 10-40%), especially after waking up the PC.

I find it hard to find out more about services.exe, and what is actually causing this issue.

However, I find it suspicious that the services.exe process has over 1,000 threads running. So this may be the first clue. Most of the threads are in RtlValidateHeap:

```
ntdll.dll!ZwWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory+0xa
ntdll.dll!RtlValidateHeap+0x3bb
kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xd
ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x21
```

So what's the recommended approach to identify issues like that?

Update: It might be that Eclipse or some of the plugins are related to this issue. After shutting down Eclipse, the thread count went down to 100-something, and is back at 1,000+ after restarting.

Comment: Without analyzing more of the call stacks of these threads, it's impossible to tell what's going on. My own `services.exe` runs 16 threads right now. So *hundreds* still sounds a bit excessive. How are you even determining those values? What tool are you using?

Comment: I just had a look at Process Explorer. Right now, I have 1,006 threads. Who offers more? ;)  Anyway, how to investigate into issues like those?

Comment: I also have threads with the identical call stack. I always considered those *normal*, but have no real clue what they actually do. If you sort the threads by Cycles Delta (so it shows the heavy workers on top), what are the stacks that generate the most work?

Comment: It's the call stack I posted. Just one thread tops the overs:

ntdll.dll!RtlGetFullPathName_U+0x2f5
ntdll.dll!TpAllocWork+0xfc
kernel32.dll!CreateThreadpoolWork+0x18
UBPM.dll+0x1216
UBPM.dll!UbpmApiBufferFree+0x1948
UBPM.dll!UbpmApiBufferFree+0x1aba
UBPM.dll!UbpmApiBufferFree+0x13b6
ADVAPI32.dll!EnableTrace+0x62a
ADVAPI32.dll!EnableTrace+0x329
ADVAPI32.dll!EnableTrace+0x22a
ADVAPI32.dll!ProcessTrace+0x1c4
UBPM.dll!UbpmOpenTriggerConsumerHandle+0x4c38
kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xd
ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x21

Comment: The top scorer has around 400,000,000 Delta cycles (ntdll.dll!RtlGetFullPathName_U+0x2f5). After that loads of threads with the stack I posted initially (not much difference in the values).

Comment: Do you have any performance analysis or profiling services/applications running? The UBPM.dll and the `EnableTrace` call sounds highly suspicious.

Comment: How can I tell? If so, it should be something that survives a restart. I was trying to hunt down another performance issue some time ago, so I ran some performance tools. I don't remember making any persistent changes, but I also cannot rule out that possibility.

Comment: I have only four `RtlValidateHeap`’s and a `TplsTiumerSet`, and a `UBPM` just popped in. Try checking to see if you have any non-default [tasks scheduled](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx). Also see what the highest memory-using and CPU-using *processes* are. Also try shutting down each service possible and check if it drops after each one.

Comment: Your system may be infected with virus. It may be using services.exe to start malware programs. That may be the reason why its thread count is going up.

Comment: Using process monitor, I checked services.exe and eclipse.exe for activity. services.exe is doing almost nothing, while eclipse.exe generated 165,000 events within 270s without any user interaction. It's mostly CreateFile, CloseFile, and Query directory. My workspace is huge.

Answer (score 2):

Normal sub-sub-processes are around 70-100 for the services.exe process. (This makes 7-10 subprocesses on average). What the OP posted was probably all of them combined.

Your running of eclipse attaches itself to services.exe because it utilizes multiple (hundreds) of built-in macros and algorithms that Eclipse doesn't need to run because it's built into Windows. These running items, as I previously mentioned, attach to services.exe as sub-processes (or threads, as you mentioned them).

This explains why it spikes when running the program. Perfectly normal. It's an intensive program, and shaves off processing time by pre-loading ALL possible algorithms and macros into Services.exe right at launch.

Hope that helps! Not much to worry about here. Scan with Malwarebytes if you're nervous it's a virus, but I've seen it before in my computer labs. Normal.

Comment: *> Normal thread-count is around 70-100 for the services.exe process.*   Huh? I had five. Oliver had 16.   Why would Eclipse load hundreds of threads into *`services.exe`* as opposed to `eclipse.exe`? `o.O`

Comment: I think you're thinking of the actual threads that make up the services.exe process. Sub-processes are everything that runs under the "service" name in Windows. For example, in Windows 8 the names of some of the "processes" are "Service Host: Local Service" and "Service Host: Local Service (Network Restricted)". Each of these processes has around 10 "sub-processes" that make up that particular service.

I can see where this could be confusing. But rest assured, it is in fact normal. The reason it doesn't load them into eclipse is mentioned above; Most commands are built in to Windows.

Comment: Windows 8 does segregate it slightly differently. For example, in Windows 7 it would be viewed as 7-10 "sub processes" while Windows 8 explains all the sub-sub-processes as well. Your comments are spot on for both operating systems, I just tried to elaborate. :)

Comment: There are most definitely not hundreds of services running under `services.exe` and I can’t imagine that Eclipse would create and run hundreds of services *anywhere*. Either way, the question is about Windows 7.

Comment: Synetech: What the OP posted was probably a combination of sub and sub-sub processes. ProcessExplorer doesn't tell the whole story. There's no way he's seeing 100+ **sub-processes**.

Comment: I checked two other PCs with Eclipse. One has 14 threads the other has 138 threads in services.exe. So I do not think this is normal behavior for Eclipse.

Comment: *> combination of sub and sub-sub processes*   `o.O` The only thing I can find anywhere about “sub processes” is in relation to Python. Either that or [incorrect terminology](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10316848/) about threads or child-processes.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not normal, who needs 1000 threads? What you can do, you can install StraceNT for Windows and debug the process what exactly it's doing.

Use -f option if it's available on Windows, it'll trace the process children.

You could also try to renice the process.

Comment: Is there anything StraceNT can do that SysInternal's Process Monitor cannot?

Comment: Yes, it can trace the process in the real time, not just show the threads. It could show the information exactly what the process is doing, all the syscalls performed to the system, etc.